# SQL find latest child status entry on an monthly aggregation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables:  'project' and 'project_status'  in a BigQuery database...

```
project
Id  Name
1   XXXX
2   YYYY
3   ZZZZ

project_status
project_id   status_date  status
1              2 Jan 2020    Good
2              4 Feb 2020    Bad
3              5 Feb 2020    On track
3              6 March 2020  Bad
```

I want to produce a monthly report of project status.  The status of a project is not updated each month. In this case the most recent status entry up to the month end is taken as the latest status

```
Month       Project  Status
Jan 2020      XXXX     Good
Feb 2020      XXXX     Good
Mar 2020      XXXX     Good
Jan 2020      YYYY     null
Feb 2020      YYYY     Bad
Mar 2020      YYYY     Bad
Jan 2020      ZZZZ     null
Feb 2020      ZZZZ     On track
Mar 2020      ZZZZ     Bad
```

For example, with project 'XXXX', there is no status update for Feb 2020 or March 2020, so the status is to be taken from the  most recent status entry of 2 Jan 2020.

Any suggestions on how to build a SQL query to deliver this report?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY` AND `ARRAY_AGG`:

```
WITH Months AS (
  SELECT DATE_SUB(month, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS last_day
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-02-01', '2020-04-02', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS month
),
Projects as (
  SELECT 1 AS Id, 'XXXX' AS Name UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS Id, 'YYYY' AS Name UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS Id, 'ZZZZ' AS Name
),
Project_Status as (
  SELECT 1 AS project_id, PARSE_DATE('%e %b %Y', '2 Jan 2020') AS status_date, 'Good' AS status UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, PARSE_DATE('%e %b %Y', '4 Feb 2020'), 'Bad' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, PARSE_DATE('%e %b %Y', '5 Feb 2020'), 'On track' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, PARSE_DATE('%e %b %Y', '6 March 2020'), 'Bad'
)
SELECT Projects.Name as Name, DATE_TRUNC(Months.last_day, MONTH) AS Month,
  ARRAY_AGG(Project_Status.status ORDER BY status_date DESC)[OFFSET(0)]  AS Status
FROM Projects 
CROSS JOIN Months 
LEFT JOIN Project_Status ON 
  Project_Status.project_id = Projects.id
  AND Project_Status.status_date <= Months.last_day
GROUP BY Name, Month
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: when I translate yuur proposal into a query I'm getting an error:  Query execution failed: - Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.

Comment: `ARRAY_AGG` helped